# How can I executing Shell Commands with Python?

Tags: python, linux

I want create folder then copy some files from other folder to this folder as shown as:

```
1-crate folder hi in /var (need root privilege  su root)
2-copy file from /var/test/myphone.txt  to folder /etc/test
3-if file myphone.txt in /root/test copy to /lib64/telphone
```

I can do all them in windows with CMD , but how can I do in Linux?

Comment: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

Comment: Can also use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: Could you really not locate any info on those topics at all? What did you search for?

Comment: You can do it in Python on both platforms, and if you had a working Python program for Windows it would work with few changes in Linux. So that's one approach. The other is to follow a tutorial on bash and learn the bash equivalents of the Windows console commands you already know.

Comment: that's completely a dupe question ! we aren't here to repeat the circle of answering duplicated questions.

Comment: @It_is_Chris, **no**. `subprocess` is preferred to `os.system()` in almost every case; https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module has extensive docs on how to put it in place. Using `os.system()` enforces starting a shell even when a shell would otherwise not be required at all, and thus increases the likelihood of shell injection vulnerabilities. Moreover, even with `shell=True`, `subprocess` lets you do something like `call(['mkdir -p -- "$1" && touch -- "$1/.empty"', '_', dirname], shell=True)` to pass `dirname` out-of-band...

Comment: @It_is_Chris, ...whereas with `os.system()` you have no way to pass data out-of-band from code at all, unless you do something like pass data through the environment (which then needs to be cleaned up after). Granted, using `shlex.quote()` (or in Python 2 `pipes.quote()`) can mitigate the vulnerabilities, but people often forget to use them -- we see a _lot_ of shell injection vulns in Python using `os.system()` in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os is a handy tool for this.

**make new dir**

```
import os
directory = "yourDir"
parent_dir = "parentDir"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
os.mkdir(path)
```

**move your file**

```
os.rename("path/to/current/file", "path/to/new/destination/file.foo")
```

shutil is another way to move your file too

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hmm that's odd. When I answered the question it was alot more informative and clear than it appears now. But I don't see that the user edited their question. Weird...

Comment: It's possible that they edited it (though it's odd to see an edit make a question worse, it does sometimes happen) in the 5-minute "grace period" after creation.